# Intel XDK webview on a Tab View App

Tags: ios, webview, intel-xdk

I have created an app in Intel XDK from the Templates and chose the "Tab View App" option. I would like to implement a webview which loads inside 1 or 2 of those tabs. I have tried to use the window.location script, but it has not worked for me. I am not very experienced with HTML5 coding so I would greatly appreciate any suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an `<iframe>` with the tab page and load a webpage

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works great.